# Why do Nuget Javascript packages copy to Scripts folder

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio, nuget

When I install e.g. jQuery from Nuget into my VS C# project, jquery.js ends up in my packages folder. This is good, since I don't want to check this file into my source control, since it's not my code and I'm never going to change it - in this context it's the equivalent of a DLL I might get via a different package. So far, so good...

Why, then, does the package installer also copy the file into the project Scripts folder, when surely it would be better to add it to the project as a link to the file in the packages folder, much as a Nuget package DLL would be referenced by the project.

Comment: It's intended for web projects, and when you host a web project the file needs to be in a retrievable location...

Comment: if you dont want it in you source control add it to the ignore list

Comment: ah, but then package restore doesn't work properly - if the file exists in the packages folder then Nuget thinks it doesn't need restoring, even if it's missing from the Scripts folder

Comment: The scripts folder is your project.  It's where you application loads its scripts from.  The packages folder is the "source" for the packages - ie your local cache so it doesn't need to download in future.  Your application does *not* read files from the packages folder (or at least, it/you shouldn't).   If you did the same with a dll, it would put the dll in packages *and* the bin folder.   Packages are not part of the project, they're a means to deliver content to your project.

Comment: yes, that's exactly my point - you have to build the project before you deploy it. Building a project with a referenced Nuget DLL will cause the DLL to be copied from packages to bin (it's never part of your source repository, there's just a reference to it in the .csproj file). I would prefer that referenced Nuget Js files were handled the same way, i.e. the build would pick them up from packages and put them wherever they need to be to run. In both cases the DLL  / JS file is never part of project's source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The team have decided to drop support for content files in nuget packages. And they are recommending to use other package managers for client side libraries like npm, bower etc. There is a built in support for them in studio 2015.
One of the reasons is that every time some client package was updated on npm repo one of the guys in microsoft team had to fetch it repackage into nuget and publish.
Check it out!