# Why in VS 2015 community Manage NuGet creates both packages and scripts folder, and hides packages folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

If I install AngularJS Core package using NuGet Package Manager, I will get a folder name "package" on the root of the project with the scripts populated, but at the same time a "scripts" folder will be created with duplicates of the same scripts.

Is there any reason for both "scripts" and "packages" folder being created?

Why if I click "Show All Files" the solution explorer will continue to hide the "packages" folder?

Answer (score 0):

The packages folder exist on the solution root and it has all the packages added to all projects inside the solution including any config or manifest files.

If you added a package once, it will be added to the packages folder and depending on this package, some folders will be created inside your project, ex: Scripts, some other packages modify web.config or add some line of code to some files, depending on what the package does.

If you added the same package to another project, it will not be downloaded again, but it will be copied from the local packages folder.

Most of the packages have DLLs, and when you add such package, the project will reference the DLL directly from the packages folder, it will not copy it to the project folder itself.

However, with packages that have content such as scripts, it must be copied to the project folder as it will be published with the project and this mainly happens with the web project itself.

Comment: So what is the reason it will create a "scripts" and "package" folder with the same scripts as in the case with AngularJS Core package?

Comment: Scripts is needed for the project to run.
Packages is created there by design in order to have a copy of all files needed, just in case you needed to add the package to another project, this is the case with most of the package managers, you must have a local copy inside your project, in NodeJS, there is a node_modules folder which is the same as Packages folder

Comment: Theoretically I can reference "packages" as I would "scripts" so I don't really need Scripts for project to run. if I integrate another project into the solution NuGet will not duplicate packages, but it will redo "scripts" for that project. So with multiple projects, I still get "scripts" created for each one in the example of the AngularJS Core package, so what we need "packages" for?

Comment: The scripts is just a special case, the normal case is only DLLs, and it depends on the package creator who decided to copy the scripts folder inside the project, if you don't want it, you can deleted, but the workaround will be that you will have to add a link to every single file inside the scripts folder that resides in the packages folder, you will end up with a big mess inside your project folder and a lot of unneeded work

Comment: I been specifically talking about NuGet. It actually seems NuGet Package Manager wants you to use the Scripts folder as in my example b/c Packages folder is not visible in solution explorer.

Comment: @MilesMorales, I agree with  freedomn-m's suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35650574/why-do-nuget-javscript-packages-copy-to-scripts-folder, as my understanding the package folder is not part of the project, the script folder is that place your application loads its scripts from.

Comment: @JackZhai I would have to say I agree with Jon's reply, that I rather have it just be in packages and after linking them have them loaded just like DLLs, there is no point in having them in both "scripts" and "packages". I have emailed NuGet.Org support for an answer but have not received a reply yet of the purpose of having both.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the package folder is not in the project root folder, it is in the solution folder. It will not be added to the solution explorer windows since it was used to manage the whole solution packages for all projects.

(1) The Scripts folder in the "Packages" folder like screen shot 1 was belong to the package, it was a part of the downloaded package.

(2) The scripts folder in the solution explorer like screen shot 2 were added to the specific project as the content folder. My understanding is that just the specific package has this function, for example, it will be added to the setup file if you want to install the app in other machine. But we couldn't install all packages in the "Package" folder for this project.

Actually Haitham Shaddad provided the correct define before, but in short, my understanding is that this script content reference was different from the assembly reference, it was related to how the package members create the package. Of course, if you have the NuGet Package Explorer tool, you would find the structures of this package.

[image]

[image]

Comment: so why are there two copies of the same scripts, like in your picture, the angular scripts are in that Scripts folder, but it will also be in Packages folder, which is hidden as shown in your picture.

Answer (score 0):

For most nuget packages, only "packages" folder will be created when you restore them. The reason you didn't see it from solution explorer is that it is just a folder created to place the nuget package files and you can change the path of the folder if you want, it is not a part of the project/solution. And if you are using version control, it is also not recommended to check the "packages" folder in to source control.

For the "scripts" folder, it is controlled by the nuget package author and the name of the folder can be anystring. If the author want the folder to be copied and added to the project, they will place it in "content" folder when create the nuget package.

Comment: so why are there 2 copies of the same scripts?

Comment: @MilesMorales When you perform a restore action, the nuget packages files are all restore into "packages" folder. And usually, the "packages" folder is outside of your project folder.  And then, the nuget detected that there are some files/folders exist in "content" folder, then it will copy these files/folders into your project folder. Refer to this link for details: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package#from-a-convention-based-working-directory